# How to copy/paste one or more files in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

i've created an AppleScript that allows me to create a folder in my computer in a desired location:

Here is the script:

```
set folderName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Folder Name:" default answer "Folder_Name")
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"

tell application "Finder"
    set newfolder to make new folder at loc with properties {name:folderName}
end tell
```

What I want now, is it possible to copy and paste files (template) in this folder that i just created with my AppleScript?

The files (template) would be placed in the same folder as the AppleScript.

And also, is it possible to create an app with my script and put the files (template) in content folder of app for works properly?

PS: I'm a newbies in AppleScript, my code in the current state it is good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this is possible. But I'm not sure I have understand all quite correct.

To create and AppleScript Application in AppleScript Editor and show the Resources Folder:

1. Choose Save.
2. In the save Dialog choose your save destination.
3. Choose File Format: Application.
4. Click Save.
5. Navigate to the App in Finder, right click it and select "Show Package Content".

The opened folder will contain a folder named `Contents` in this there is the `Resources` folder. Put the files there or create them there.

To get the path to this folder use:

```
set resPath to (path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:"
```

<strike>(The above script won't work as excepted in AppleScript Editor. You have to run the script as an app)</strike>(Seems that you can now test this out of Script Editor)

You can now copy your template files like this:

```
set resPath to (path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:"

tell application "Finder" to duplicate resPath & "aTemplate.txt" to loc
```

BTW: You can access the Resources folder directly via the Scrip Editor if you click Bundle Contents in the toolbar.